# How can I set the value of a struct variable on an interface slice?

Tags: reflection, go

How can I set `testEntity.Val` that is contained in `[]interface{}{}` using reflection?

```
type testEntity struct {
    Val int
}

func main() {

    slice := []interface{}{testEntity{Val: 3}}
    sliceValue := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    elemValue := sliceValue.Index(0)

    // Prints: can set false
    fmt.Println("can set", elemValue.Elem().Field(0).CanSet())

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/lxtmu9ydda

Can someone explain why it works with `[]testEntity{}` but not `[]interface{}{}` as shown here: http://play.golang.org/p/HW5tXEUTlP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to  [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8321) this behaviour is correct.

### Semantics

The reason is that there is no equivalent syntax in Go that allows you to take the address of a value masked by an `interface{}` value.

This behaviour can be demonstrated in a simplified example. If you have the following code

```
slice := []testEntity{testEntity{Val: 3}}
slice[0].Val = 5
fmt.Println(slice)
```

then the line

```
slice[0].Val = 5
```

actually translates to

```
(&slice[0]).Val = 5
```

To modify a slice element it must be addressable, or else the value would not have been propagated back to the slice. Go does that automatically for you. Now let us modify the example and use an `interface{}` slice instead:

```
slice := []interface{}{testEntity{Val: 3}}
slice[0].Val = 5
fmt.Println(slice)
```

This example will obviously not work since `interface{}` does not have a field called `Val`. So, we would need to assert the type of `slice[0]`:

```
slice[0].(testEntity).Val = 5
```

While the type system is now content with that line, the addressability rules are not. Now the change of `Val` would be lost since we are operating on a copy of `slice[0]`. To counter this we would have to take the address of `slice[0]` and this, as you will see, leads us nowhere:

```
slice := []interface{}{testEntity{Val: 3}}
(&slice[0]).(*testEntity).Val = 5
fmt.Println(slice)
```

This code cannot work since `(&slice[0])` is not of type `interface{}` anymore but `*interface{}`. As a consequence we cannot assert that value to `*testEntity` since only interface values can be asserted. This means that **there is no Go syntax for setting an interface value in a slice** and since reflection only models Go's behaviour, this will not work with reflection as well, even if it is technically possible.

We could imagine some syntax that takes the address of the underlying value of `slice[0]` while retaining the type but this syntax does not exist. The same goes for reflection. Reflection *knows* the underlying type of the interface and could easily use that information to provide a type-safe pointer to `slice[0]`'s underlying value so we can use `Set()` on that, but it does not since Go does not.

### Technical reason

The reflect package uses several flags to mark the abilities of `Value` objects. The two flags related to setting values using `Set` are `flagAddr` for addressability and `flagRO` for marking `Value` objects as read-only (e.g. unexported attributes). To set using `Set()`, `flagRO` must be unset and `flagAddr` must be set.

If you look into the definition of [`Value.Elem()` in `reflect/value.go`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/reflect/value.go?name=go1.3#827) you will find the [line responsible](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/reflect/value.go?name=go1.3#844) for handing the kind flags to the new value:

```
fl := v.flag & flagRO
// ...
return Value{typ, val, fl}
```

In the snipped `v` is the current value, `elementValue` in your case. As you can see, this will only copy the read-only flag and **not the `flagAddr`** that is needed for setting a value using `Value.Set()`. Changing that line to

```
fl := v.flag & (flagRO|flagAddr)
```

will enable us to use `Set()` but will also make it possible to change the underlying value of a `interface{}` value to any other value, breaking type safety.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for placing the issue, if you did. I think the example http://play.golang.org/p/uM5mwL1zxW in the issue is slightly wrong however. I expect `elemValue.Elem().Field(0).CanSet()` to be true not `elemValue.Elem().CanSet()`. I'll update the issue accordingly and mark this as correct once we have a response.

Comment: After some more thought I think this behaviour that Go has is an unintuitive quirk of the language. It turns out there is no way I can see to change `Val` inside `[]interface{}{testEntity{Val:3}}` even without using reflection (http://play.golang.org/p/KPYOVPfIqm) therefore the reflect package does not allow it either. It is just unintuitive that I can change `Val` in `[]testEntity{testEntity{Val:3}}` but not `[]interface{}{testEntity{Val:3}}`. What do you think?

Comment: @Dan Yes, this is a tad unintuitive but only because you know that it is perfectly possible with reflection (even though it would require most likely non-profitable changes). I have updated my answer according to the new information.

Answer (score 2):

While Go won't let you legally do what you want, you can still technically do it using unsafe. Just adding this to the discussion since you wanted to know how to do it and why you can't do it is answered already.

```
test := (*testEntity)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&slice[0])) + 4))
test.Val = 5
fmt.Println(slice)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/vNdht-DMKg

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a pointer to the struct, not a value, you can't set on a copy.

http://play.golang.org/p/lXUglGDOKN

```
func main() {

    slice := []interface{}{&testEntity{Val: 3}}
    sliceValue := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    elemValue := sliceValue.Index(0)

    // Prints: can set false
    fmt.Println("can set", elemValue.Elem().Elem().Field(0).CanSet())

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it doesn't fully answer my question on why I can set Val using `[]testEntity{testEntity{Val: 3}` but not `[]interface{}{testEntity{Val: 3}`.

Comment: @Dan AFAICS the type of `sliceValue.Index(0)` is never something else than `interface{}` and inherits the read-only flag.

Comment: @nemo maybe it is true for an interface slice but definitely not true for a struct slice ([http://play.golang.org/p/S2LTMN9KAA](http://play.golang.org/p/S2LTMN9KAA)). I want to know why this might be the case because surely an interface slice containing structs should be the same as a struct slice containing structs when it comes to mutating the structs with reflection.

Comment: Because an interface is an immutable reference type. Call Elem on the interface's reflect.Value and you gain access to its underlying value to mutate that.

Comment: @tomwilde assuming I understand you correctly, look at my code snippet in the question. This is what I tried to do and it does not work which is why I am asking the question.

Comment: You'll have to store an "addressable" value in the interface, [such as a pointer (click for example)](http://play.golang.org/p/lXUglGDOKN).

Comment: So why does `[]testEntity{testEntity{Val: 3}}` allow me to mutate `Val` with reflection? How come this is addressable but `[]interface{}{testEntity{Val: 3}}` isn't? Why does adding a struct to an `[]interface{}{}` slice make it immutable whereas adding a struct to a struct slice does not?

Comment: Not 100% sure but my guess is, `interface{}` holds a copy, while `[]testEntity` holds a reference, hence why it works with pointers but not values, but that's just an educated guess.